# Will a Devil Fruit user swim if he/she is in contact with Kairoseki?

Tags: one-piece

We know that Kairoseki nullifies the Devil Fruit powers and sea immobilizes the Devil Fruit users. So hypothetically, what will happen if a Devil Fruit user tries to swim while he/she is in contact with Kairoseki?

Comment: Why the '-1'? I don't know it, and just asking if anyone out there knows. Is it that bad of a question that it gets down voted in minutes.

Comment: I didn't -1, but I also don't understand your question. Why wouldn't they drown? It seems pretty obvious to me that they would unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @LoganM Well kairoseki completely nullifies the devil fruit aspect of a user, then shouldn't the drowning curse be nullified too. Its just a thought that's why I am asking whether someone knows about it??

Comment: @AbhilashK Two negatives don't make a positive (in this case). See [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/why-is-kairosekis-effect-more-powerful-than-the-sea) for an more indepth explaination of what Kairoseki is. Exposing a Devil Fruit user is alike exposing them to the see, putting them in the ocean has no added effect.

Comment: @Krazer I gave one of those 3 answers. It is stated that they don't have same wavelengths; only similar, thus the effects would be different, kairoseki negates the power and sea immobilizes them. However nothing is mentioned about their combination.

Comment: @Krazer As for the kairoseki, it only works after direct contact with the user him/herself, not with the object they created, or effect they are causing.

Comment: @AbhilashK If you have a set of cuffs that makes your whole body a cold as if it was in a blizzard and you put them inside a blizzard, they'd still be a cold  if they were in a blizzard.

Comment: @Krazer I don't understand the metaphor and the meaning you are trying to say, sorry but please explain. :(

Comment: @AbhilashK It's an analogy. If I have an item that simulates being in  situation (e.g, freezing in a blizzard) and put myself in the actual situation as the effect from the item, I'd still be freezing in a blizzard.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12101/discussion-between-krazer-and-abhilashk)

Comment: @Krazer But what if another item removes the effect of freezing altogether, then being in a blizzard should have no effect.

Comment: @AbhilashK - Have a look at [my answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6509/1604) for the original question which made you ask this question. The effects of Kairoseki and Sea are almost the same. There is not enough evidence to prove that they affect a DF user different, thus, answering this question as, *No, they can't swim in water even if they are in direct contact with Kairoseki*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't. The [Sea Stone](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kairoseki) drains the Devil Fruit user's body of energy rendering them unable to move (as if they were paralyzed), and negates their Devil Fruit powers (but not the [cursed side effects](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#Side_Effects_of_Devil_Fruits)). This is the same effect as if they were exposed to the ocean. Since they can't move or breathe underwater without [special assistance](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Coating#Flutter_Kick_Coating), they will ultimately drown.