# Why can Devil Fruit users use their abilities while wet?

Tags: one-piece

My understanding was that the sea is supposed to weaken devil fruit users and rob them of their powers. The [One Piece Wikia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Fruit#Side_Effects_of_Devil_Fruits) elaborated:

> Devil Fruit users are susceptible to all types of water, not just seawater. This includes the white sea surrounding Skypiea. [Oda] elaborated on this, saying that "moving" water, like rain or waves, does not weaken Devil Fruit users, while standing water does.

The Wikia also states the users cannot use their powers while submerged.

> Even if a part of the user is submerged, they cannot use their Devil Fruit powers, no matter how much or how little is submerged. However, if the user's body has been permanently altered by the fruit, then the user's ability can be manipulated by outside sources (eg Luffy's neck was stretched while submerged at Arlong Park).

My questions:

- How did Ajoki freeze the ocean?

  [image: Ajoki freezing an ocean]

  May I emphasize he submerged his hand in the sea to use Ice Age?
- How did Luffy fight Crocodile while wet at Marine Ford?

  [image: Luffy fighting Crocodile while wet]

  He was dripping wet after having fallen into the sea. Does the water not weaken him since he was now submerged? I assumed since sea stone worked just by touching it and it has the same effect as the ocean, then by having part of the ocean "touch" him would drain his power.

Are these just plot holes or am I missing something?

Comment: If small part of a fruit user is expose to sea water it doesn't affect them. Only if almost all part of their body is exposed to it. There is an episode about Brooke and Luffy about this. I'll add it to the answer if i see it again.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

- Kuzan freezes the water without touching it. So the water doesn't nullify him. Think like how Ace tries to vaporize sea water with fire. He only creates those fire he isn't the fire in that case.
- Sea water doesn't cancel Devil Fruit powers it only weakens it for the *Paramecia type*.

---

From [Wikia article on Kuzan](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuzan):

> In addition, Kuzan is one of the few Devil Fruit users who has adapted
>   their powers to travel efficiently across the sea. In his case,
>   freezes the water underneath Ao Chari then rides across the sea, due
>   to the water freezing as the wheels pass over it. This freezing
>   ability, which can be used on a very large scale, renders Kuzan one of
>   the few Devil Fruit users who can actually counteract the weakness of
>   falling into a large body of water and drowning, as he can just freeze
>   the water and stand on the ice.

From the [Wikia article on Logia](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuzan)

> Logia Devil Fruits allow a person to **create**, **control**, and **transform**
>   into a natural element or force of nature, depending on the fruit. The
>   user can transform partly, or completely.

---

For Luffy's case, check this [post](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6509/11077).

Answer (score 0):

Well in episode 302, there is a fight between Lucci and Luffy, they are underground under the sealevel, Lucci slams the wall, seawater starts to flow in and they, both fruit users, stand in the water like almost nothing is happening. True that the water level is reaching only their knees or something at that height.

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate further on your answer? You recounted an event which demonstrates that Devil Fruit users can use abilities while wet but you didn't answer the OP as to why this is even possible in the first place.